DDEV: ddev-router won't start on Fedora 39
Since Janary I'm working on a Mautic Project and I use ddev boundled with Mautic to start and stop Mautic for development purposes.
Everything was working fine.
The project run on a Fedora 39 machine.
But two months ago ddev wont'start properly due to ddev-router problem.
Running ddev start exit with the error:
Starting ddev-router if necessary... 
 Container ddev-router  Created 
 Container ddev-router  Started 
Failed to start mautic-5.1.0: ddev-router failed to become ready; debug with 'docker logs ddev-router' and 'docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" ddev-router'; logOutput=, err=ddev-router container is unhealthy: , more info with [
    docker logs ddev-router
    docker inspect --format "{{ json .State.Health }}" ddev-router | docker run -i --rm ddev/ddev-utilities jq -r


I've followed all the suggestions described in ddev troubleshooting page.
Running docker logs ddev-router seems ok compared to the same project that work fine in another machine based on Linux Mint.
It seems that one of the Fedora updates changed something that made ddev-router fail to start.
Hope that someone help me to solve this issue.

Please show what it says under "debug with". (A gist on gist.github.com would be best.) docker logs ddev-router and docker inspect --format "{{json .State.Health }}" ddev-router

It would help a bunch if you'd do a ddev debug test and provide the results in a gist on gist.github.com also.

Hi @rfay thank you for the answers. Here you can find a gist with all requested outputs.

Thanks, that helps me lots. I'll comment on the gist with some suggestions because comments here are too limited. What I'd really like you to do is to join us in Discord, https://discord.com/invite/5wjP76mBJD where we can have a more interactive conversation.

More detail at https://gist.github.com/comanche76/d45b561a42f41e3684fe98e4bd9aff51?permalink_comment_id=5143372#gistcomment-5143372
